# Google Yahoo etc login buttons on Ask Question

Tags: feature-request, openid

Please could the Login buttons (like the one you click to sign in with a Google account) be added to just underneath where you ask a question if your logged out. It's annoying to type a whole question only to find that I'm logged out, and I don't know the URL to put in the OpenID box to log in with my Google account so i have to go to the login page copy the URL and comeback and paste it in. It would just be much easier if there were the Accounts button as well as the manual textbox.

Comment: What this "only to find that I'm logged out"? I don't understand, you mean you can be logged out of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes , even though I'm always logged in to my Google Account, sometimes stackoverflow doesn't see that and I don't log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just type **yahoo.com** (or gmail.com, myopenid.com, etc) in the login area and the rest will happen automatically:

[image]

Verified and working; we also support people entering their email addresses here (for openid providers that are email services), like `example@yahoo.com` or `foo@gmail.com`

Comment: It's not a very useful feature though if no one is aware of it, is it?